# Output in CSV format using AWK command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, csv

I have a **input.txt** file with following format:

```
Name  age  number       address
mark  23   89756342192   chennai
david 40   70214789023   delhi
```

How do I create a CSV file from a TXT file as per the following example? Thanks.

```
mark,23,89756342192,chennai
david,40,70214789023,delhi
```

Below is the script i have written

**printrep.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
Headers=["Name","Age","Phone","Address"];
count=$(wc -l < $name)
i=0;
echo "Headers[0] + ' , ' +Headers[1]+ ' , ' +Headers[2] + ' , ' +Headers[3] + ' , ' +Headers[4]";
while [ $i -lt $count ]
do
        read line | awk FS=' ' OFS="," '{print $0}'
        i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

The above code is unable to display the output. And i Can't figure what is wrong. Please help I am a beginner to shell scripting

Comment: `printrep.sh` would benefit from being passed through https://shellcheck.net/ It's clear that either you've not tried to run it or else you're not telling us the errors you have received.

Comment: @roaima when i made the block bold the ** came automatically, i didn't realise it.

Comment: @roaima no leading/trailing spaces. I have not copy pasted the code, So didn't include the shebang line. But am using bash shell

Comment: @roaima i have tried running it but no output is displayed and i can't figure out what is wrong it the code. I am a begginer to shell scripting

Comment: No-one can reliably help you until you fix the question to match reality

Comment: @roaima I edited the post and posted it again. Thanks for the issues

Comment: Are there supposed to be blank lines in the source and destination files?

Comment: no. It's just for the clarity i have added extra space.

Comment: Please don't add extra space. Provide the file in the right format

Comment: As the `bash` tag you included states - `For shell scripts with errors/syntax errors, please check them with the shellcheck program (or in the web shellcheck server at https://shellcheck.net) before posting here.`. That way we don't have to tell you about several issues the tool could tell you about.

Answer (score 4):

bash: the IFS variable is key here. This is bash specific for the use of arrays and `read -a`

```bash
IFS=,
while IFS=$' \t' read -ra fields; do echo "${fields[*]}"; done < input.txt
```

awk: very terse: `$1=$1` rewrites the current line using the output field separator, and `1` to print the line.

```bash
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=, input.txt
```

[miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): this requires the input file to *not* have empty lines: convert from "pretty-print" format to csv

```bash
mlr --p2c cat input.txt
```

This also correctly handles commas in the input:

```bash
$ cat input.txt
Name  age  number        address
mark  23   89756342192   chennai
david 40   70214789023   delhi
alice 24   42            paris,texas

$ mlr --p2c cat input.txt
Name,age,number,address
mark,23,89756342192,chennai
david,40,70214789023,delhi
alice,24,42,"paris,texas"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of ways:

```
cut --output-delimiter="," -c1-6,7-11,12-25,26- < file
tr -s " " "," <file
sed -e "s/  */,/g" <file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r -i 's/\s+/,/g' file.txt
```

```
output

cat file.txt 
Name,age,number,address
mark,23,89756342192,chennai
david,40,70214789023,delhi
```